# Connecting to Web Service with apache HttpClient

Tags: java, rest

The [Appache HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) library seems to work fine for communicating with a regular web site, but is unable to connect to a web service.

I am building come components to run inside a Java Desktop application that will communicate with a Web Service-REST using the Jersey framework.  The web service is running and I can communicate it with my web browser and with the Test-Web-Service function in netbeans.

The client code works fine if I try to read from a regular web page or even the default page for the Glassfish web server running on my machine.
Why is it that when I try to reach the web service with my client program (code below) do I get a 404 Not Found error from the web server?

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.client.*;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.*;  //HttpHead, HttpPut, HttpGet, etc...
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class ApacheClientDemo {

  public static void demo() throws IOException {           
     String uri = "http://localhost:8080/Proctorest/resources/helloWorld";
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
     System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));       
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        demo();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
  }
}
```

When going to a regular web site on-line or a non-web service site hosted locally, the output is

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Followed by the content of the web page.

The code above gives me

```
  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

---

Edit: Below is the code for the web service.
The web service code was generated from a Netbeans sample project.
[image: Netbeans Sample Web Service project]

```
/*
* DO NOT ALTER OR REMOVE COPYRIGHT NOTICES OR THIS HEADER.
*
* Copyright 1997-2010 Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
*
* Oracle and Java are registered trademarks of Oracle and/or its affiliates.
* Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.
*
* The contents of this file are subject to the terms of either the GNU
* General Public License Version 2 only ("GPL") or the Common
* Development and Distribution License("CDDL") (collectively, the
* "License"). You may not use this file except in compliance with the
* License. You can obtain a copy of the License at
* http://www.netbeans.org/cddl-gplv2.html
* or nbbuild/licenses/CDDL-GPL-2-CP. See the License for the
* specific language governing permissions and limitations under the
* License.  When distributing the software, include this License Header
* Notice in each file and include the License file at
* nbbuild/licenses/CDDL-GPL-2-CP.  Oracle designates this
* particular file as subject to the "Classpath" exception as provided
* by Oracle in the GPL Version 2 section of the License file that
* accompanied this code. If applicable, add the following below the
* License Header, with the fields enclosed by brackets [] replaced by
* your own identifying information:
* "Portions Copyrighted [year] [name of copyright owner]"
* 
* Contributor(s):
* 
* The Original Software is NetBeans. The Initial Developer of the Original
* Software is Sun Microsystems, Inc. Portions Copyright 1997-2007 Sun
* Microsystems, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
* 
* If you wish your version of this file to be governed by only the CDDL
* or only the GPL Version 2, indicate your decision by adding
* "[Contributor] elects to include this software in this distribution
* under the [CDDL or GPL Version 2] license." If you do not indicate a
* single choice of license, a recipient has the option to distribute
* your version of this file under either the CDDL, the GPL Version 2 or
* to extend the choice of license to its licensees as provided above.
* However, if you add GPL Version 2 code and therefore, elected the GPL
* Version 2 license, then the option applies only if the new code is
* made subject to such option by the copyright holder.
*/

package helloworld;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;

/**
* REST Web Service
*
* @author mkuchtiak
*/

@Stateless
@Path("/helloWorld")
public class HelloWorldResource {

    @EJB
    private NameStorageBean nameStorage;
    /**
    * Retrieves representation of an instance of helloworld.HelloWorldResource
    * @return an instance of java.lang.String
    */
    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getXml() {
        return "<html><body><h1>Hello "+nameStorage.getName()+"!</h1></body></html>";
    }

    /**
    * PUT method for updating an instance of HelloWorldResource
    * @param content representation for the resource
    * @return an HTTP response with content of the updated or created resource.
    */
    @PUT
    @Consumes("text/plain")
    public void putXml(String content) {
        nameStorage.setName(content);
    }
}

/////////// NameStorageBean .java

import javax.ejb.Singleton;

/** Singleton session bean used to store the name parameter for "/helloWorld" resource
*
* @author mkuchtiak
*/
@Singleton
public class NameStorageBean {

    // name field
    private String name = "World";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens when you enter `http://localhost:8080/Proctorest/resources/helloWorld` from your web browser or using `curl`/`wget`?

Comment: Since the helloWorld resource implements the @get method, the web browser gives me the page I would expect. That's really the question. Why is glassfish responding to a web browser request, but not a Java client request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can not see how you deploy the service.

try change (camel case is unusual for a service)

```
String uri = "http://localhost:8080/Proctorest/resources/helloWorld";
```

to lowercase "helloworld"

```
String uri = "http://localhost:8080/Proctorest/resources/helloworld";
```

or try

```
String uri = "http://localhost:8080/helloworld";
```

**HOW TO GET ROUTE**

**U:...\HelloWorld1\HelloWorld1\web\WEB-INF\sun-web.xml**

```
<sun-web-app error-url="">
  <context-root>/HW</context-root>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</sun-web-app>
```

a) //localhost:8080/**HW** from `<context-root>/HW</context-root>`

**U:...\HelloWorld1\HelloWorld1\web\WEB-INF\web.xml**

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hw/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

b) //localhost:8080/HW/**hw** from `<url-pattern>/hw/*</url-pattern>`

**U:....\HelloWorld1\HelloWorld1\src\java\helloworld\HelloWorldResource.java**

```
.....
/**
 * REST Web Service
 *
 * @author mkuchtiak
 */

@Stateless
@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {
....
```

c) //localhost:8080/HW/hw/**helloworld** from `@Path("/helloworld")`

put a)b)c) parts from your 3 files together.

**Notice: the url Netbeans shows is wrong, only /HW is correct**

```
...
    Incrementally deploying HelloWorld1
    Completed incremental distribution of HelloWorld1
    run-deploy:
    Browsing: http://localhost:8080/HW/resources/helloWorld
...
```

---

```
....
public static void demo() throws IOException {           
     String uri = "http://localhost:8080/HW/hw/helloworld";
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
     System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));       
  }
....
```

OUTPUT

```
debug:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

<html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>
```

Comment: I am deploying the service to GlassFish from Netbeans. This is the demo app that can be created from the new project wizard, and I added some adfitional resources to it, but in the code above I'm just testing the resource that comes with the demo. The spelling of he URI is not the issue; I checked the spelling and case of the @resource annotation and my web browser can get to the URI fine.